# torch doesn't recognize cuda and I can't use my gpu for training

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I have an RTX 3060 GPU but
`print(torch.cuda.is_available())` is returning false. What should I do?
I also have run the nvidia-smi command in cmd and it is the result: NVIDIA-SMI 512.36       Driver Version: 512.36       CUDA Version: 11.6
So how should I handle the problem? btw I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: What happens when you call the `set_device` method? If your gpu still isn't being recognized you should double-check that you have the correct driver installation (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) and check that `torch.cuda.is_initialized()` `returns` `True`.

Answer (score 1):

did you download the right version of PyTorch? https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and choose what version you want with CUDA etc.

As far as I know, PyTorch includes its own version of cuda and does not need a local installation of cuda, that also means that PyTorch is not influenced by the local installation of cuda.

Comment: pytorch does not include Cuda https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-it-required-to-set-up-cuda-on-pc-before-installing-cuda-enabled-pytorch/60181. It sounds more like the pytorch bindings are mismatched i.e. the wrong version of pytorch was downloaded